# What would happen if you add ice to an isolated system of water that is already at 0°C?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, ice

So here’s my question:
Say there is some ice at -2°C. And water at 0°C. The ice is added to the water. Now this is a completely isolated system. There is no heat exchange whatsoever with the environment. In this case, what will happen?

It’s obvious that heat should flow from the water to the ice, causing it to increase in temperature. What happens to the water then? I’ve heard about supercooling properties. Will water be supercooled? Assuming supercooling, will both the ice and water reach an equilibrium temperature below 0? If this happens, won’t the existing ice trigger some sort of chain reaction causing the entire thing to turn into ice like in those videos where people bang supercooled water bottles? And then assuming supercooling isn’t possible, will part of the water freeze? If so, where will it begin to freeze from?

So many questions. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Consider the latent heat of freezing.

Comment: Why would it become supercooled? Heat will travel from the water to the ice until the system is in equilibrium. That's about all. It seems like you believe the water will continue cooling which is not possible

Comment: @josephh because the water is already at 0°C. What happens to it as it gives heat?

Comment: Some of the water will freeze to form ice, until the original ice is at 0 C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the amount of water. If  the negative energy content of the ice between -2 and 0 C in frozen form is enough to freeze the water, the water is freezed, else the water is freezed partly on the surface until the ice reaches 0C and energy transport stops in the equilibrium of coexistence of water and ice at 0C.